# Combine svg filters (`feTurbulence`? `feColorMatrix`? others?) to get single color textured effect

Tags: svg, svg-filters

How can I combine svg filters to get both:

- a "mottled" texture and
- a single colour spectrum (e.g. different levels of blue-and-white)?

I'm able to use an `feTurbulence` filter to get the "mottling" effect. I'm also aware of the `feColorMatrix` filter to desaturate an image, i.e. "lose" the color and convert the image to grayscale. However, I haven't been able to combine them to do the latter after the former. When I've tried, the "rainbow" colouring effect of `feTurbulence` filter seems to persist. My (intermediate) desired result is a grayscale image. Beyond that, I then want to convert that grayscale image to a single colour, e.g. convert it from a gray-and-white spectrum to a blue-and-white spectrum. Perhaps those need to be in separate steps or perhaps they can be combined in a single step.

I show code below which applies the `feTurbulence` filter (in combination with an `feComposite` filter) to some text and an svg shape. This code works for me in Google Chrome, but I haven't checked it (nor do I currently need it) in other browsers. In case you are reading this question using a browser for which this filter does not work, a screen capture of output is provided here:

[image]

I eventually want to convert that to something like the following (which I created using image manipulation software, not web technologies):

[image]

I don't really need a universal cross-browser solution; I only need this to work in Chrome.

```css
.filtered{
  filter: url(#filter);
  font-size: 100px;
}
p {
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <filter id="filter">
      <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" result="TURBULENCE" baseFrequency="0.1" numOctaves="5" seed="2" />
      <feComposite operator="in" in="TURBULENCE" in2="SourceAlpha" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div  class="filtered">
  Some Text<br/>
  <svg>
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="300" height="100" fill="black" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

[These slides](https://www.slideshare.net/mullany1/cirque-du-filter-cssdevconf-2013) by Michael Mullany gave me some good pointers for figuring this out, as did [the MDN web docs for SVG filters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/feColorMatrix).

I discovered the following solution (although others are also possible). I use the `result` attribute value of `feComposite` filter element as the `in` attribute value for the `feColorMatrix` filter element which uses a `type` of "matrix". To understand the `values` attribute the following slide from Michael Mullany's talk helped me:

[image]

I entered a value of 1 for k3, understanding that to mean that I am adding a fixed full-blue offset to all the pixels in the eventual image, multiplying them by a factor of 0.5 from the output of the `feComposite` filter element's alpha channel (although I could have arbitrarily also put that value of 0.5 into any of the "R->A", "G->A", "B->A" or "A->A" locations).

If you are looking at this answer from a browser that is not capable of showing the code snippet results properly, the output that I get from the code below when using Google Chrome is the following:

[image]

```css
.filtered{
  filter: url(#filter);
}
p {
  margin: 0;
  font-size: 100px;
}
```

```html
<svg width="0" height="0">
  <defs>
    <filter id="filter">
      <feTurbulence type="fractalNoise" result="myTurbulence" baseFrequency="0.1" numOctaves="5" seed="2" />
      <feComposite operator="in" in="myTurbulence" in2="SourceAlpha" result="myComposite"/>
      <feColorMatrix in="myComposite" type="matrix"
        values="0   0   0   0   0
                0   0   0   0   0
                0   0   0   0   1
                0   0   0   0.5 0" />
    </filter>
  </defs>
</svg>
<div  class="filtered">
  <p>Some Text</p>
  <svg>
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="300" height="100" />
  </svg>
</div>
```